# Как сделать эту функцию что бы с строки получился масив(ниже)

Tags: javascript

Как сделать эту функцию что бы с строки получился масив который принимает строку как параметр, последовательно переставляет все символы в строке с нулевого индекса на последний и возвращает массив со полученными комбинациями

```
scrollingText("robot")

Повертає:
[ "ROBOT",
  "OBOTR",
  "BOTRO",
  "OTROB",
  "TROBO" ]

``
```

Answer (score 5):

Точно знаем, что кол-во повторений будет `str.length`. Поэтому просто создаем массив с такой длинной и сразу записываем туда по два куска массива (разделяем по текущему индексу).

```js
const scrollingText = (str) => 
  Array.from({ length: str.length}, 
    (_, i) => [...str].splice(i).join `` + [...str].splice(0, i).join ``);

console.log(scrollingText('abcd'));
```

Comment: Однако `=> str.slice(i) + str.slice(0, i)` тоже справляется =)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, согласен. Не сразу в голову приходят такие нюансы методов :)_